# How does Gmail's inbox show a track order button in the end of a subject line for e-commerce mails

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

A track order button is appended to the end of a subject line in Gmail's inbox. How do they do it?

Comment: I dont understand the question, could you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the e-commerce company that you receive emails from might have whitelisted for the action button to be displayed.

Those buttons are called Action buttons and its a Smartmail feature from Google to access the data quickly without even opening the email.

In order to get your companies email to be whitelisted you can also register your email by following the guidelines mentioned by Google in this [page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).

Hope that helps!